# PUT request: Required request body is missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web

Given this Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ShowCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShowCase.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "submit", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public void getFormKeys(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {
        System.out.println(formData.keySet().stream().collect(joining(",")));
    }

}
```

And this curl request:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "arg1=val&arg2=val" http://localhost:8080/submit
```

With Spring Boot 1.2.5 the method is invoked correctly and prints the form-keys.

With Spring Boot 1.3.8 the method is not invoked, but a warning is logged instead:

```
WARN 17844 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public void web.ShowCase.getFormKeys(org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
```

What is necessary in Spring Boot 1.3.8 so that this PUT request is working again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the @EnableWebMvc annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableWebMvc
public class ShowCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ShowCase.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "submit", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public void getFormKeys(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData) {
        System.out.println(formData.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
    }

}
```

Comment: It works. Is there a reason why this annotation is required now or what it changes?

Comment: From the spring-boot documentation: `Normally you would add @EnableWebMvc for a Spring MVC app, but Spring Boot adds it automatically when it sees spring-webmvc on the classpath. This flags the application as a web application and activates key behaviors such as setting up a DispatcherServlet.`[https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/](source)

Comment: I think they removed it because will only use this annotation when you want to take full control of your mvc configuration, avoiding some default behaviors configured by spring boot.